# Can't connect to remote machine - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: flask, geoserver, cesiumjs

I am using Nginx server and Ubuntu for my website. My geoserver is running and functioning well. I pass data to geoserver through localhost:

`const terrainProvider = await Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({ "url": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver", "layerName": "cesium:raw_data_wms" }); const imageryProvider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({ "url": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", "parameters": { "format": "image/png", "transparent": true }, "layers": "cesium:imegary-wms", "maximumLevel": 15 });`

When I run FlaskApp the app works well, but when I try to enter the website the map page shows error as  **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**
Full Error is here

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&tiled=true
localhost:8080/geose…lities&tiled=true:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
map:92 Uncaught (in promise) 
FJ
response
: 
undefined
responseHeaders
: 
undefined
statusCode
: 
undefined
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

How to solve this **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** ?

Comment: where does `nginx` figure in your setup? where is GeoServer installed?

Comment: both are installed in my Ubuntu. /etc/nginx and GeoServer in /usr/share/geoserver . But I'm accessing the website from another windows computer which is connected to the same network.

Comment: Probably a firewall issue then

Comment: Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: look at your firewall to see why it is blocking your connection